# 5-letter password at least 2 letters are uppercase

Tags: combinatorics

My attempt at solving:

$$\text{Number of passwords with at least 1 uppercase} = 52^5-26^5 $$
$$\text{Number of passwords with exactly 1 uppercase} = 5\cdot 26 \cdot 26^4 $$
$$\text{Number of passwords with at least 2 uppercase} = (52^5-26^5)-(5\cdot 26 \cdot 26^4) $$

I multiplied by 5 the number of passwords with exactly 1 uppercase to account for the other positions but I am unsure if it's right

Comment: I think this looks okay, except they can be simplified a bit.

Comment: What you have done is correct.